# Android sdk manager doesnt download packages

Tags: android, eclipse

When I open de sdk manager I get a Log window with the following:

```
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Validate XML
Parse XML
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.1, API 7, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.1, API 12, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 3
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16, revision 4
  Found SDK Platform Android 4.2.2, API 17, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 3
  Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 7, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 8, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 9, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Samples for SDK API 10, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 11, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 12, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 13, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 14, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 15, revision 2
  Found Samples for SDK API 16, revision 1
  Found Samples for SDK API 17, revision 1
  Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 17
  Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
  Found Android SDK Tools, revision 22.0.1
  Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 17, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 16, revision 2
  Found Sources for Android SDK, API 17, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
  Found Google APIs, Android API 3, revision 3
  Found Google APIs, Android API 4, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 5, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)
  Found Google APIs, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 11, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 12, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 2
  Found Google APIs, Android API 16, revision 3
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12, revision 2
  Found Google TV Addon, Android API 13, revision 1
  Found Google APIs, Android API 17, revision 3
  Found Android Support Library, revision 13
  Found Android Support Repository, revision 1
  Found Google Repository, revision 1
  Found Google Play Licensing Library, revision 2
  Found Google Play APK Expansion Library, revision 3
  Found Google Play services, revision 7
  Found Google USB Driver, revision 7
  Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 4
  Found Google AdMob Ads SDK, revision 11
  Found Google Analytics App Tracking SDK, revision 3
  Found Google Web Driver, revision 2
  Found Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, revision 3
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
  Found Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM), revision 3
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 16, revision 4
  Found MIPS System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Validate XML: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Parse XML:    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10, revision 2
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 16, revision 1
  Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
Done loading packages.
Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Fetched Add-ons List successfully
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-8.xml, reason: Socket java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml, reason: Socket java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml, reason: Socket java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml, reason: Socket java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/mips/sys-img.xml, reason: Socket java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/sys-img.xml, reason: Socket java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
Download interrupted: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 1
Download interrupted: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

If I try to select a package It doesnt get dowloaded, the same window appears. I have been using eclipse with the sdk of android without any problem months ago. Today I opened the IDE and tried to download something with no luck. Does anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solution: Open SDK Manager click tools in the top menu -> options and turn on "force h ttps://...sources"

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager --> Packages ---> Reload. It will reload all the new packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using proxy servers, then you can also set the proxy. The screen shot is given below:

[image: Changing proxy]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my Mac by installing the latest version of Java - this refreshed the certificates and cleared the algorithm error. I reached that by way of failing to export the certificates before importing some from another, working machine.

[java.io.IOException: Invalid Keystore format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052700/java-io-ioexception-invalid-keystore-format)