# Tomcat 7 and invalid keystore format

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keystore

I'm trying to connect to Tomcat through https on a remote server; I've found many answers, but no one has worked for me; I'm using Apache, Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

First, I created the certificate keystore writing:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

after I' ve edited "/etc/tomcat7/server.xml" to use ssl on port 8443:

```
<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
                keystoreType="JKS"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                keystoreFile="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool"
                keystorePass="***********" keyAlias="tomcat"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

where ********** is the password; restarting Tomcat through:

```
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

I'm getting the following error in file "/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out":

```
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:650)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore(JSSESocketFactory.java:392)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeystore(JSSESocketFactory.java:291)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:489)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.init(JSSESocketFactory.java:434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.createSocket(JSSESocketFactory.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:397)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more
```

---

The keystore type is JKS, I've verified it through the command:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list
```

which has returned:

```
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

tomcat, 17-Oct-2015, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 33:14:32:DD:DA:20:BF:CF:70:32:F5:0E:E9:F1:C1:5B:4E:C3:DB:AB
```

where $JAVA_HOME is "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64";

So when I try to connect to "https://myServerIp:8443/" or to "https://myDomainName:8443/" I get "Unable to connect" error.

Comment: `keytool` is the program that is used for managing key stores so I guess the path for the key store file (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool`) in your tomcat configuration is incorrect.

Comment: @Titus if I run `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool -list` (which is the same of writing `$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -list` ) it gives me the data at the bottom of the question, does it mean that this is a correct keystore file?

Comment: On Linux system the keystore file is save by default in the user's home folder `/home/userName/.keystore`

Comment: when you call `keytool -list` the `keytool` program will read that file (`.keystore`)

Comment: Now i've tried to specify the path using `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool` but it has returned 'keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format', i've looked for '/home/userName/.keystore' but i haven't this file, in /home/ directory i've only an empty folder "lost+found"

Comment: `.keystore` starts with `.` so it is a hidden file. The command should be `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /home/userName/.keystore`. Like I've said, `keytool` is a program (not a key sore) and `.keysotre` is the file that contains the keys (the key store).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

just to further support this answer for beginners like me. On Windows OS

1. First go to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8**,
    Press `Shift + right-click` to open command pront: write this `keytool.exe -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /{user.name}/.keystore`,
    A sequence of question will then follow after that you will see a new **.keytore** generated at the specify path
2. Now you need to go to server.xml and modify this two `keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"` with the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works correctly, in short:

- I **specified the path of the `.keystore`** file
- I **configured Tomcat to use this file**

---

Thanks to @Titus I've understood where the problem was: when I run the command

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

or the command

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat
```

the program `keytool` create a file `.keystore` in a folder of the server; the directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin` contains a file named `keystore`, but this file is not correct to setup tomcat or for some reason it doesn't work in my case.
To specify the path of the file `.keystore` we can run the command

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /path/.keystore
```

and after that I've configured Tomcat editing the file `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml` with the file just created:

```
<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
                keystoreType="JKS"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
                keystoreFile="/path/.keystore"
                keystorePass="************" keyAlias="tomcat"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: You still have not understood. The `bin` directory does *not* contain a keystore. It contains an *executable file* called`keytool`, which isn't a keystore. The `.keystore` file *generated by* the keytool is the keystore.

Comment: As commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071504) there could be a 'filtering' problem when the keystore is treated as text rather than binary. Set resource's `<filtering>false</filtering>` in your `maven-resources-plugin` (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502504)), or use `<files>` rather than `<configfiles>` in your `maven-cargo-plugin` (see https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Configuration+files+option.html)