# Invalid Keystore Format while signing the react native app

Tags: react-native

I have developed a react native application. I am trying to push it to google playstore. I am following the same steps mentioned in react native official doc https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android, and generated a kestore file called `wings-prod.keystore` file.

When I try signing the app using `./gradlew signingReport` I am getting `Invalid keystore format` format. Can someone help with this?

```
Error: Failed to read key wings-prod from store "/Users/asrinivasarao/Projects/winggs-app/winggs-customer/winggs/android/app/wings-prod.keystore": Invalid keystore format
```

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this same problem today in my React-Native app. The solution was to upgrade my JDK version from 8 to 11. Android Studio > Preferences > Build Execution Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle. Select (or download then select) Gradle JDK version corretto-11.

To give proper credit, I was tipped off to this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69270811/5788142

Comment: The same worked for the Ionic Capacitor project. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### Try:

The command for generating a keystore file is (
Remember to run this command in the android/app directory, atleast if you are on a mac.)

```sh
keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -storepass android -alias androidreleasekey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

On Windows:
The keytool must be run from C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin

Follow the [official guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)

Also, keep in mind that it should be the same key, if you have already published the app to the play store.

### If any of the above does not work:

1. try deleting the .gradle file and running the

```sh
./gradlew clean
```

2. Check the Java Version if it is the same at

```
D:\Program Files\Java\
```

and

```
D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

Additionally check if you are running on JDK11 if you are on react native 0.65 and above.