# Android Java Keystore corrupted when in a different machine

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, fastlane, android-app-signing

I created a release Java Keystore (.keystore) file to publish my apps on Google Play Store on a machine with Windows. The .keystore file is working, as I can publish my apps successfully. But when I use the same release .keystore file on a Mac, I get the following error message when  trying to submit my app to Google Play Store:

> Failed to read key release from store "/Users/samuelpetroline/Documents/bem-hortifruti-app/android/app/release.keystore": Invalid keystore format

I am using the same file on both OS and they're placed at the same location in my project. I also tried to copy the file with different tools, as I thought I was corrupting the file somehow when copying the file.

Is there something specific I should be looking for when using the same .keystore file on different machines/OS ?

PS: I don't know if this info is relevant but I am using React Native and building/deploying my app with fastlane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue recently. I was able to fix the problem by changing my Java version in Android Studio from 8 to 11. Android Studio > Preferences > Build Execution Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle. Select (or download then select) Gradle JDK version corretto-11.

To give proper credit, I was tipped off to this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69270811/5788142