# rvm fails to install jruby

Tags: macos, rvm, jruby, keystore

I am unable to install jruby(tried 9.1.5.0) using rvm on OSX 10.1.3.2

```
$ rvm install jruby-9.1.5.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.13/x86_64/jruby-9.1.5.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Requirements installation successful.
$JAVA_HOME was empty, setting up JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home, if it fails try setting JAVA_HOME to somethi>
Cloning from https://github.com/jruby/jruby.git, this may take a while depending on your connection.
HEAD is now at 73846e9e78 Merge pull request #4818 from philr/file_open_read_raise_eisdir_on_windows
remote: Counting objects: 11, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 11 (delta 6), reused 11 (delta 6), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
From https://github.com/jruby/jruby
   600f8bd833..788cd5b3f3  jruby-9.1  -> origin/jruby-9.1
From https://github.com/jruby/jruby
 * branch                  master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up to date.
git checkout 9.1.5.0
Copying from repo to src path...
jruby-9.1.5.0 - #/Users/prasad/.rvm/src/jruby-9.1.5.0/mvnw...........
Error running '/Users/prasad/.rvm/src/jruby-9.1.5.0/mvnw',
please read /Users/prasad/.rvm/log/1516906519_jruby-9.1.5.0/mvnw.log

$ cat /Users/prasad/.rvm/log/1516906519_jruby-9.1.5.0/mvnw.log
[2018-01-26 00:57:31] /Users/prasad/.rvm/src/jruby-9.1.5.0/mvnw
current path: /Users/prasad/.rvm/src/jruby-9.1.5.0
GEM_HOME=/Users/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1
PATH=/Users/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/prasad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/prasad/.jenv/sh>
GEM_PATH=/Users/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1:/Users/prasad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global
command(1): /Users/prasad/.rvm/src/jruby-9.1.5.0/mvnw
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.3.9/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
  at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
```

Some information for debugging.

```
~$ xcode-select -v
xcode-select version 2349.
~$ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.3 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
~$ uname -a
Darwin Matrix 17.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0: Thu Nov  9 18:09:22 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.31.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
~$ keytool -list -keystore cacerts
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: cacerts
~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
~$ jenv versions
system
1.8
* 1.8.0.152 (set by /Users/prasad/.jenv/version)
oracle64-1.8.0.152
~$ keytool -list -keystore
```

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
    keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

Comment: seems like keystone file is unsupported, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052700/java-io-ioexception-invalid-keystore-format

Comment: maybe this will help: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/4883

Comment: @Traveler Added some more information.