# Java SSL/TLS with KeyStore and ServerSockets

Tags: java, sockets, security, ssl, keystore

I am coding a SocketServer Lib with an TLS/SSL Function, but i have a Problem in my Code.

If I load the Keystore File, it throws an IOException, but the Cert gets fully displayed in the Browser.

My Code:

```java
SSLServerSocketFactory factoryIO;
FileManager certificateIO = new FileManager(CacheHandler.fileIO.getPath("database") + "letsencrypt.jks");
char[] passphraseIO = "12345678".toCharArray();

if (certificateIO.exits()) {
    //this.socketIO = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(this.networkIO.getPort(), 10, this.networkIO.getAddress());
    //this.socketIO = this.getContext().getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(this.networkIO.getPort(), 10, this.networkIO.getAddress());

    // Load Key Store.
    KeyStore storeIO = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    storeIO.load(certificateIO.stream(), passphraseIO);

    // Initialize Key Manger.
    KeyManagerFactory managerIO = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    managerIO.init(storeIO, passphraseIO);

    // Initialize Trust Manger.
    // TrustManagerFactory trustIO = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    //trustIO.init(storeIO);

    // Initialize SSL Context with Trust and Key Manager.
    SSLContext contextIO = SSLContext.getInstance(this.protocolIO);
    contextIO.init(managerIO.getKeyManagers(), null /*trustIO.getTrustManagers()*/, null);


    factoryIO = contextIO.getServerSocketFactory();
    // ((SSLServerSocket) this.socketIO).setWantClientAuth(true);
    //((SSLServerSocket) this.socketIO).setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"});
    //((SSLServerSocket) this.socketIO).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
```

I tried many things but i can't get it to run without this error, it worked i while a go but i don't know what i made, to produce this error.

Which throws the following Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:658)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at sun.security.util.AnchorCertificates$1.run(AnchorCertificates.java:61)
    at sun.security.util.AnchorCertificates$1.run(AnchorCertificates.java:52)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.util.AnchorCertificates.<clinit>(AnchorCertificates.java:52)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.checkFingerprint(AlgorithmChecker.java:214)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.<init>(AlgorithmChecker.java:164)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.<init>(AlgorithmChecker.java:118)
    at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:157)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:207)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.isTrusted(JarVerifier.java:610)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:530)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:363)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:289)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:164)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:190)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.canUseProvider(JceSecurity.java:204)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:179)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyAgreement(JsseJce.java:269)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce$EcAvailability.<clinit>(JsseJce.java:418)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(JsseJce.java:194)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:371)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:185)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:304)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(SSLContextImpl.java:42)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:432)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1634)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1592)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.network.server.ServerSocket.startIO(ServerSocket.java:203)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.network.server.ServerSocket.start(ServerSocket.java:172)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.web.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:44)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.web.WebService.start(WebService.java:54)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.service.ServiceHandler.start(ServiceHandler.java:63)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.service.ServiceHandler.start(ServiceHandler.java:48)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.guardian.GuardianHandler.init(GuardianHandler.java:121)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.guardian.GuardianHandler.load(GuardianHandler.java:82)
    at de.bytestore.mytriox.Controller.main(Controller.java:11)
```

I generate my KeyStore file via following Command:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass 12345678 -dname "CN=localhost, OU=Developers, O=Bull Bytes, L=Linz, C=AT"
```

Comment: You should post the complete stacktrace. Now we're even missing the exception message!

Comment: I am sorry, had an issue in the markdown ^^

Comment: There is `DualFormatJKS` in there, I wonder if it first tries to load it as "JKS" or "PKCS12" key store and then finds out it needs to use the other one... Just a hunch, not an answer. Are you using an older Java, such as Java 8 maybe?

Comment: Yes, I am using Java 8, but I use the Method instance for JKS and no other Store Type.

Comment: What happens if you specify the key store explicitly as "JKS" in `keytool`? Are you sure that `keytool` itself is also using Java 8? If you are using e.g. Maven, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052700/java-io-ioexception-invalid-keystore-format)

Comment: I have these files in a separate folder, outside the class path. I tried it with the absolute path from java 8 where the keytool is stored, but nothing worked for me. Likewise, I think I will try to check if the file is really a "JKS" File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my Problem by Changing the Java Version.

**The Oracle one gave Problems with my Code, I switched to Java 14, and it worked...**

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the stream Method of my KeyStore.

I converted the URL to a URI to open a Stream, which didn't worked because the relative Path was wrong.

So I using now an FileInputStream and getting the Exception for a wrong path.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's outside of my perception, thanks for reporting back. Not so useful to others as the problem is outside `KeyStore` in case anybody is looking this up.

Comment: Fwiw, the error is thrown based on the first two words of the file.  https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/JavaKeyStore.java  So it had to be either bad data or bad i/o.

Comment: Sorry for commenting back, but my error is not resolved fully. I thought it, but there's the same Error many lines before.